# set servletConfig by java

Tags: java, spring, servlets

in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>aliases</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

now I want to instantiate the servlet in java, how can I set `contextConfigLocation`?

Comment: You *are* setting the `contextConfigLocation`.

Comment: *Why* do you want to instantiate the servlet? The application container does that for you, you don't need to instantiate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

before the filters section (*you need to adjust the path*)
and:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

before the servlet section